# SQL Syntax error in PDO Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am running this query in PHP PDO

```
$stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare("SELECT * from integra_status where type = :type and maintenance_fromdate <= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) and maintenance_todate => DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY) ");
```

but im getting this SQL Syntax error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=> DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)' at line 1' in /home/integra/public_html/service_status/index.php:56 Stack trace: #0 /home/integra/public_html/service_status/index.php(56): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 /home/integra/public_html/index.php(124): include('/home/integra/p...') #2 {main} thrown in /home/integra/public_html/service_status/index.php on line 56
```

Comment: `maintenance_todate =>` should be `maintenance_todate >=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`maintenance_todate =>` should be `maintenance_todate >=`

Answer (score 3):

`>=`, not `=>` ... note the reversal of the order.